# basement bathtub straddling a crater

Tags: plumbing, basement, code-compliance

we got this house recently. i was working on paint and finishing our basement bathroom.. trying to remove the baseboard trim surrounding the the bathroom shower, i noticed that it came out suspiciously easily. poking around i found the drywall around the shower wall to be of a wet/damp cardboard consistency, and was punctured by your basic nail removal tool.

in anycase i was able to rip apart around 1 feet high "drywall" from the floor with my bare hands. what i discovered was even more "scandalous" (?).

the entire "bulb" portion of the tub is hovering on a crater. the drain pipes and the vent pipes resting on soil are naked and clearly visible from the 1 feet high hole, above the bathroom floor in the drywall i created. infact 2 of the four rounded edges of the tub are floating in air.

is this normal/correct. if not, how do i fix this?

Edit: 
Added images showing the full views, and the view of the left-hand side of the tub.

[image: Full View][image: Left View]

The tub part of the tub is hovering in air. And it looks like they dug the basement concrete floor to do the plumbing and never filled it back up.

Comment: A photo would help tremendously in understanding the scope of your issue. By "bulb", do you mean the entire bottom bulge of the tub? Or just the drain area? The wet drywall is likely another issue entirely, unless that's caused by stagnant water under the tub (and somehow the crater has something to do with it).

Comment: Definitely in need of photos to even attempt to explain, however if you have bare soil underneath your bathtub, I'm also curious as to the style of your home. Is it a ranch on foundation, slab, crawlspace? In what region and in what country are you?

Comment: Thanks alt and BrownRedHawk. I have added pictures. The house is the basement of a split entry ranch on foundation. New England.

Comment: Tubs are frequently supported by their rims only. Are there any issues with your tub? (Squishy bottom, cracks, ...?) If you run a lot of water through (including using the overflow) do you see any leaks?

Comment: Thanks Aloysius, so it is ok for the the tub to be supported only by their rims. I have not detected any leaks although, it drains slowly. I have also not tested the overflow.